# How to validate field across multiple lists

Tags: workflow, validation

So I'm created a number of different lists and libraries with workflows attached.
When someone creates a new job, the document is uploaded to the Job directory (library).
If it classified as a specification document it is copied into the Spec library. Likewise for  quote and an enquiry documents.
What would be the best method for ensuring the "Job Name" field (which is featured in every list and library) remains consistent throughout the site?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by consistent, you want to ensure as docs are moved around the job name remains the same?

You could use a lookup field to a Job list, which will narrow down the possibilities and remove some human error by way of someone typing in something incorrectly. Also, by using a master list, you can create a dashboard view for your jobs, letting you see all of the related content in one page. Let me know if you want some more info on creating an easy dashboard.

HTH

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. Currently in each library the Job Name field is single line of text - not what we want. Most of the time the column is automatically filled in because the document is often just copied from the "drop box" library. Can I still have a workflow auto populating it if it is a lookup field?
And yes please an easy dashboard would be fantastic!

Comment: Yes, a workflow can handle populating a lookup. Check out my blog post on creating a dashboard view: http://davidlozzi.com/2012/08/02/creating-an-item-detail-dashboard-view-of-your-joined-lists-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I'm gonna give that a go on monday! Thanks very much. Perhaps you'd be able to tell how to populate the "job name" (lookup field) from my workflow. I have no issues when its single line of text, but now that its a lookup im not having any luck...

Comment: I'd have to give it a whirl myself to remember how to do it. I think you can create a variable object that performs the lookup to get the item ID? Sorry, I forget. However, I'm assuming the user specifies the value when they upload the doc the first time, you should be able to just copy the field value from list to list, if not, try a lookup in the WF.

Comment: Saw your comments on my blog http://davidlozzi.com/how-can-i-help/. This place might be better for the conversation ;). Can you start off with the lookup field in your Drop Box? If you're going to allow users to enter a job name, there's no guarantee it'll match the jobs directory every time.

Comment: The Jobs Directory is populated from what they put in the drop box. For example, if someone uploads a document called "My Spec" and gives it a Job Name of "My Job", the first step is to create an entry in the Jobs Directory list called "My Job". Only then is the document copied over to the specification library.
(EDIT: Pressed Enter too soon!)

Comment: Oooo.... Now I get it. When you add the item to the Jobs Directory list, you should be able to get an ID, which you can then reference in the lookups. If it's not that clear, I'll have to try it out myself.

Comment: I finally have it! Hooray! Thank you so much for your help.
The problem was entirely caused by my ignorance, I have now managed to learn a bit more about it and have it working beautifully. Thanks again, I really appreciate it :)